# power series solving

Tags: calculus, power-series

Solve the functions power series on $c=0$ and where it converges:

$f(x)= {x^3 \over {1-2x^2}}$

I'm kind of confused about this whole concept, but was able to solve all this far,  I think I have to put it like this first: $x^3 \cdot {1 \over {1-2x^2}}$
but how do I continue from here?

Answer (score 1):

One may use the standard geometric result
$$
1+u+u^2+...+u^N=\frac{1-u^{N+1}}{1-u}, \quad |u|<1, \tag1
$$ then setting
$$
u=2x^2, \quad |u|<1,
$$ and letting $N \to \infty$, one gets
$$
\frac{x^3}{1-2x^2}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty 2^n x^{2n+3}, \quad |x|<\frac1{\sqrt{2}}. \tag2
$$

Answer (score 0):

It is well known that $$\frac{1}{1-u^2}=1+u^2+u^4+u^6+\dots\qquad |u|<1.$$
Thus, if $|\sqrt{2}x|<1$, that is, $|x|<\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$, then
$$\begin{align}
\frac{x^3}{1-2x^2}&=x^3\cdot\frac{1}{1-(\sqrt{2}x)^2}\\
&=x^3\cdot\bigg[1+(\sqrt{2}x)^2+(\sqrt{2}x)^4+(\sqrt{2}x)^6+\dots\bigg]\\
&=x^3+(\sqrt{2})^2x^5+(\sqrt{2})^4x^7+(\sqrt{2})^6x^9+\dots\\
&=x^3+2x^5+2^2x^7+2^3x^9+\dots\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}2^nx^{2n+3}
\end{align}$$